# Error stacktrace with angular 2 and webpack 2

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to setup dev environment with angular2/webpack2 stack and i have next webpack config:

```
// Helper: root() is defined at the bottom
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

// Webpack Plugins
var autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");



module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig(env) {

  var config = {};

  config.devtool = "source-map";

  config.entry = {
    "main": "./src/main.ts",
    "vendor": "./src/vendor.ts",
    "polyfills": "./src/polyfills.ts"
  }

  config.output = {
    "chunkFilename": "js/[name].[hash].chunk.js",
    "filename": "js/[name].js",
    "path":  root("dist"),
    "sourceMapFilename": '[file].map',

  };

  config.resolve = {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".css", ".html"]
  };

  config.module = {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/,                                                                       loaders: ["awesome-typescript-loader", "angular2-template-loader"] },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: "style-loader", loader:  ["css-loader", "postcss-loader"] }) },
      { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,     loaders: ["file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?"] },
      { test: /\.html$/,                                                                     loaders: ["raw-loader"] }
    ]
  };

  config.plugins = [
    new ExtractTextPlugin(
      { filename: "css/[name].[hash].css" }
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      root("./src")
    ),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        sassLoader: {},
        postcss: [autoprefixer({ browsers: ["last 2 version"] })]
      }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      chunksSortMode: "dependency"
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ["vendor", "polyfills"]
    }),
  ];

  config.devServer = {
    contentBase: './src',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    quiet: true,
    stats: 'minimal' // none (or false), errors-only, minimal, normal (or true) and verbose
  };

  return config;
};

function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```

[image]

**my problem**: i can see valid ts source-map files (see "2" on pic), but when i got exception i see only references to compiled bundle (see "1" on pic) in stacktrace. 
**question**: How can i configure webpack to see correct references to source-map *.ts files, but not to compiled bundle js files?

Comment: Have you tried config.devtool = 'inline-source-map' ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Error.stack` is generated by V8, which knows nothing about source maps, however if you do `console.log(error)` DevTools will replace references using source maps, but `zone.js` wraps original error and extracts stack as string, so DevTools can not replace references any more. You could try to use stacktrace mappers like [sourcemapped-stacktrace](https://github.com/novocaine/sourcemapped-stacktrace).

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Can you provide any better solution to debug Angular 2 apps, which builds via Webpack? Or can you provide some eample how can i inject  sourcemapped-stacktrace to catch all uncatched errors in  Angular2?

Comment: I prefer debugging in Chrome directly, optionally using `debugger` statement, however you could also debug in WebStorm/Intellij Idea. https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/09/debugging-webpack-applications-in-webstorm/

Comment: but how can you detect top stacktrace frame of your client code using Chrome? for example, in my example i manually throw exception and i know where is it. But in real life i don't know who throws this exception and where is i should add debugger statement.

Comment: There is `Pause on exceptions` option in Chrome debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In angular2 we can do same level of debugging only thing is we need add a debugger keyword like we do in node then open the console and the moment it reaches your file on leftist see call stack thats where you can find file path at that point and it redirects you directly through ts file so debugging will be easy and as cool as before